# Getting unknown error from MQSAgent in BizTalk 2020

Tags: ibm-mq, biztalk, biztalk-2020

I've implemented MQSAgent before and it was working. Had to reinstall it on my server. First, the user/name and password are correct. The user is a member of the COM group. After I confingured it, it returns:

> T22]:IMQSAgent.IsDataPresentEx() : Encountered NotImplementedException:

> Reason: The method or operation is not implemented.

The Com service is started. Also checked DTS and everything looks correct.[image]

I've never received this error before. Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there were two MQSAgent.dll files that were not the same, in the BizTalk Server directory. One had a file size 90KB and the other 199KB. Not sure how these were in the directory both as MQSAgent.dll. Deleted the 90KB file and MQSAgent is now posting messages on MQ.